# Android Fragment Crashing from NPE onCreate

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm stuck and a new pair of eyes would be appreciated. I have my `MainActivity` calling a `fragment` on a `button` click. It was pulling it in fine, then I added `database` calls in the `fragment` and now its crashing. In my logcat its saying im getting a null pointer exception in my onCreate. Here is the code and logcat.

**fragment code**

```
public class StatsFragment extends Fragment {
    public static MySmokinDatabase mySmokinDatabase;
    public static Model model;
    View view;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
            ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        model = MainActivity.model;
        mySmokinDatabase = new MySmokinDatabase(getActivity());

        TextView daysText = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.days); 
        TextView totalText = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.total); 
        TextView aveText = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.ave);
        try {
            daysText.setText("" + (model.getDays())); 
            totalText.setText("" + mySmokinDatabase.getTotal());
            if (model.getDays() > 0) 
            aveText.setText("" + (float) mySmokinDatabase.getTotal() / (float) model.getDays());
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("*** DEBUG ***", "Error");
            System.out.print("error" + e);
        }

        // Create, or inflate the Fragment’s UI, and return it.
        // If this Fragment has no UI then return null.
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stats_frag, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

**button handler**

```
public void statisticsHandler(View view) {
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    Log.v("*** DEBUG ***", "Statistics Handler");
    ft.replace(R.id.main_container_Id, new StatsFragment());
    ft.commit();
}
```

**logcat**

```
03-27 15:40:03.767: W/dalvikvm(862): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
03-27 15:40:03.867: E/AndroidRuntime(862): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-27 15:40:03.867: E/AndroidRuntime(862): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-27 15:40:03.867: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at com.example.smokin4tomsullivan.StatsFragment.onCreateView(StatsFragment.java:24)
03-27 15:40:03.867: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:829)
03-27 15:40:03.867: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
03-27 15:40:03.867: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
03-27 15:40:03.867: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1397)
03-27 15:40:03.867: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:426)
03-27 15:40:03.867: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
03-27 15:40:03.867: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-27 15:40:03.867: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-27 15:40:03.867: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
03-27 15:40:03.867: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-27 15:40:03.867: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-27 15:40:03.867: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
03-27 15:40:03.867: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-27 15:40:03.867: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move this closer to the top before you grab the views. You are getting an NPE because the findViewById calls are returning null.

```
// Create, or inflate the Fragment’s UI, and return it.
// If this Fragment has no UI then return null.
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stats_frag, container, false);
```

before you grab the views. Then do

```
TextView daysText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.days); 
TextView totalText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.total); 
TextView aveText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ave);
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer not only fixed the crash it displayed the values. Answer will be accepted asap

Answer (score 2):

Set this `view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stats_frag, container, false);` before getting your views as below

Use `getActivity()` instead of `getView()` while getting the views.

i.e

```
   TextView daysText = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.days); 
    TextView totalText = (TextView)  getActivity().findViewById(R.id.total); 
    TextView aveText = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ave);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, my app no longer crashes. However the values are not displaying. The answer below solved both problems. You get an upvote, but he gets the check mark

Comment: @IrishWhiskey is your Textviews part R.layout.stats_frag, then set the context view before actually getting the values. i.e   set this   view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stats_frag, container, false);    before getting Textviews